# socket.io shows dependency warnings when installing using npm

Tags: reactjs, webpack, socket.io

I am trying to install socket.io using npm, however whenever I run

```
npm run build:dll
```

I get the warnings/errors:

```
Building the Webpack DLL...
Hash: e4aec7398e03ac59c7bf
Version: webpack 3.5.5
Time: 3456ms
                      Asset     Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
reactBoilerplateDeps.dll.js  4.55 MB       0  [emitted]  [big]  reactBoilerplateDeps
chunk    {0} reactBoilerplateDeps.dll.js (reactBoilerplateDeps) 3.84 MB [entry] [rendered]

WARNING in ./node_modules/socket.io/lib/index.js
108:11-32 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

WARNING in ./node_modules/ws/lib/BufferUtil.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'bufferutil' in '/Users/***/node_modules/ws/lib'
 @ ./node_modules/ws/lib/BufferUtil.js 35:21-42
 @ ./node_modules/ws/lib/Sender.js
 @ ./node_modules/ws/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/engine.io/lib/server.js
 @ ./node_modules/engine.io/lib/engine.io.js
 @ ./node_modules/socket.io/lib/index.js
 @ dll reactBoilerplateDeps

WARNING in ./node_modules/ws/lib/Validation.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'utf-8-validate' in '/Users/***/node_modules/ws/lib'
 @ ./node_modules/ws/lib/Validation.js 10:22-47
 @ ./node_modules/ws/lib/Receiver.js
 @ ./node_modules/ws/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/engine.io/lib/server.js
 @ ./node_modules/engine.io/lib/engine.io.js
 @ ./node_modules/socket.io/lib/index.js
 @ dll reactBoilerplateDeps

WARNING in ./node_modules/uws/uws_darwin_46.node
Module parse failed: /Users/***/node_modules/uws/uws_darwin_46.node Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
 @ ./node_modules/uws ^\.\/uws_.*$
 @ ./node_modules/uws/uws.js
 @ ./node_modules/engine.io/lib/server.js
 @ ./node_modules/engine.io/lib/engine.io.js
 @ ./node_modules/socket.io/lib/index.js
 @ dll reactBoilerplateDeps

WARNING in ./node_modules/uws/uws_darwin_47.node
Module parse failed: /Users/***/node_modules/uws/uws_darwin_47.node Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
 @ ./node_modules/uws ^\.\/uws_.*$
 @ ./node_modules/uws/uws.js
 @ ./node_modules/engine.io/lib/server.js
 @ ./node_modules/engine.io/lib/engine.io.js
 @ ./node_modules/socket.io/lib/index.js
 @ dll reactBoilerplateDeps

WARNING in ./node_modules/uws/uws_darwin_48.node
Module parse failed: /Users/***/node_modules/uws/uws_darwin_48.node Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
 @ ./node_modules/uws ^\.\/uws_.*$
 @ ./node_modules/uws/uws.js
 @ ./node_modules/engine.io/lib/server.js
 @ ./node_modules/engine.io/lib/engine.io.js
 @ ./node_modules/socket.io/lib/index.js
 @ dll reactBoilerplateDeps

WARNING in ./node_modules/uws/uws_darwin_51.node
Module parse failed: /Users/***/node_modules/uws/uws_darwin_51.node Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
 @ ./node_modules/uws ^\.\/uws_.*$
 @ ./node_modules/uws/uws.js
 @ ./node_modules/engine.io/lib/server.js
 @ ./node_modules/engine.io/lib/engine.io.js
 @ ./node_modules/socket.io/lib/index.js
 @ dll reactBoilerplateDeps

WARNING in ./node_modules/uws/uws_darwin_57.node
Module parse failed: /Users/***/node_modules/uws/uws_darwin_57.node Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
 @ ./node_modules/uws ^\.\/uws_.*$
 @ ./node_modules/uws/uws.js
 @ ./node_modules/engine.io/lib/server.js
 @ ./node_modules/engine.io/lib/engine.io.js
 @ ./node_modules/socket.io/lib/index.js
 @ dll reactBoilerplateDeps

WARNING in ./node_modules/uws/uws_linux_46.node
Module parse failed: /Users/***/node_modules/uws/uws_linux_46.node Unexpected character '' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
 @ ./node_modules/uws ^\.\/uws_.*$
 @ ./node_modules/uws/uws.js
 @ ./node_modules/engine.io/lib/server.js
 @ ./node_modules/engine.io/lib/engine.io.js
 @ ./node_modules/socket.io/lib/index.js
 @ dll reactBoilerplateDeps

WARNING in ./node_modules/uws/uws_linux_47.node
Module parse failed: /Users/***/node_modules/uws/uws_linux_47.node Unexpected character '' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
 @ ./node_modules/uws ^\.\/uws_.*$
 @ ./node_modules/uws/uws.js
 @ ./node_modules/engine.io/lib/server.js
 @ ./node_modules/engine.io/lib/engine.io.js
 @ ./node_modules/socket.io/lib/index.js
 @ dll reactBoilerplateDeps

WARNING in ./node_modules/uws/uws_linux_48.node
Module parse failed: /Users/***/node_modules/uws/uws_linux_48.node Unexpected character '' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
 @ ./node_modules/uws ^\.\/uws_.*$
 @ ./node_modules/uws/uws.js
 @ ./node_modules/engine.io/lib/server.js
 @ ./node_modules/engine.io/lib/engine.io.js
 @ ./node_modules/socket.io/lib/index.js
 @ dll reactBoilerplateDeps

WARNING in ./node_modules/uws/uws_linux_51.node
Module parse failed: /Users/***/node_modules/uws/uws_linux_51.node Unexpected character '' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
 @ ./node_modules/uws ^\.\/uws_.*$
 @ ./node_modules/uws/uws.js
 @ ./node_modules/engine.io/lib/server.js
 @ ./node_modules/engine.io/lib/engine.io.js
 @ ./node_modules/socket.io/lib/index.js
 @ dll reactBoilerplateDeps

WARNING in ./node_modules/uws/uws_win32_48.node
Module parse failed: /Users/***/node_modules/uws/uws_win32_48.node Unexpected character '�' (1:2)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
 @ ./node_modules/uws ^\.\/uws_.*$
 @ ./node_modules/uws/uws.js
 @ ./node_modules/engine.io/lib/server.js
 @ ./node_modules/engine.io/lib/engine.io.js
 @ ./node_modules/socket.io/lib/index.js
 @ dll reactBoilerplateDeps

WARNING in ./node_modules/uws/uws_win32_51.node
Module parse failed: /Users/***/node_modules/uws/uws_win32_51.node Unexpected character '�' (1:2)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
 @ ./node_modules/uws ^\.\/uws_.*$
 @ ./node_modules/uws/uws.js
 @ ./node_modules/engine.io/lib/server.js
 @ ./node_modules/engine.io/lib/engine.io.js
 @ ./node_modules/socket.io/lib/index.js
 @ dll reactBoilerplateDeps

ERROR in ./node_modules/socket.io/lib/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/***/node_modules/socket.io/lib'
 @ ./node_modules/socket.io/lib/index.js 7:11-24 9:13-26
 @ dll reactBoilerplateDeps
```

I have tired adding  node: { fs: 'empty' } to my webpack conf, and deleting and node_modules folder, however it doesnt fix it. This issue has now also appeared on one of my old projects which I have updated.

I have found people with similar issues, however none of the fixes have worked.

```
 "socket.io": "^2.0.4",
 "webpack": "3.5.5",
```

I tired installing socket.io-client and I get even more errors (edit: I seem to need both for a react app).

My webpack config is the same as the react boilerplates. Using a Mac and Webstorm if this helps.

Comment: socket.io-client shouldn't give you any node related errors. try wiping node_modules, package.lock and reinstalling without socket.io only client version

Comment: also what version of npm are you running

Comment: I removed socket.io, only installed socket.io-client, and removed the package.lock. Worked perfectly - thanks!

Comment: I am not sure that I want to be using the socket.io-client version though?

Comment: are you using webpack to build a server side application?

Comment: I'm guessing because you have `reactjs` as a tag and that you're using webpack, that you in fact want to be using the client version. of course you will also need the non-client version, but not within the same application

Comment: I am yes. I need the socket.io-client for the react component to talk to the server. What do you mean not within the same application? socket.io is for the server and client is for the react components. socket.io will not build with webpack

Comment: yeah the server shouldn't be building with webpack. that's why i mean by separate apps. basically like two separate directories, one with your react app + webpack and one with your node server. here's an example: https://github.com/alex-wilmer/rater

Answer (score 1):

I found that I had used:

```
node: {
        fs: 'empty',
}
```

In the wrong place and needed to add:

```
noParse: /ws/,
externals: ['ws'],
```

to webpack.base.babel

This cleared up all of the errors

Answer (score 0):

use [Webpack node modules externals](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-node-externals) to ignore all modules from node_module dir and built-in modules

var nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
...

```
module.exports = {
    ...
    target: 'node', // in order to ignore built-in modules like path, fs, etc. 
    externals: [nodeExternals()], // in order to ignore all modules in node_modules folder 
    ...
};
```